# NameError: name 'word' is not defined ,python

Tags: python-3.x, nltk

I'm trying to create a chatbot using nltk. Here I have a list which I'm converting to lower case and to its root word using LancasterStemmer. I get this error:

> NameError: name 'word' is not defined.

How can make this code better?

```
words = [stemmer.stem(w.lower()) for w in word.split() for word in words if word not in ignore]
```

```
words = sorted(list(set(words)))
```

I'm new to python.

Answer (score 0):

You have to flip your `for` loops, start with the `word` loop, and then the `w` loop:

```
words = [stemmer.stem(w.lower()) for word in words for w in word.split() if word not in ignore]
```

This is similar to an ordinary `for` loop, you can't have this:

```
for w in word.split():  #  << what is `word` here? it's not defined yet.
    for word in words:
```

Instead, you should have this:

```
for word in words:
    for w in word.split():  #  << `word` is defined here from the outer loop.
```